# how do i strip line in file using python

Tags: python-2.7

**Input:**

```
dataaaaaaaaaaaaa,

dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
```

**output:**

```
dataaaaaaaaaaa,
dataaaaaaaaaaa,
dataaaaaaaaaaaa,
```

**code:**

```
with open('file') as f:
   for line in f:
     if not line.isspace():
       print lie.strip()
```

**out put of this code is:**

```
dataaaaaaa
aa,
dataaaaaaaa,
dataaaaaaaa,
```

space and empty line are removed starting and ending of the file but single is break into two lines. I want to remove only spaces and empty lines.

How can I achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can try this:

```
result = []
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        print('len: ', len(line))
        if len(line) == 1:
            continue
        else:
            result.append(line)

with open('file', 'w') as f:
    for line in result:
        f.write(line)
```

Note that it will rewrite the original file so it will become:

```
dataaaaaaaaaaaaa,
dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
```

The code removes the empty line and leaves the others untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and its working fine(obviously after changing 'lie' to 'line' in code). Are you sure that you are checking it right?

Comment: sorry that's typo error still am having same issue at the end of each line 4 to 5 characters strip into new line. Please give me hint to handle this situation.

Comment: But I am not facing any problem with your code. May be some problem with your file. Create a new file(say temp.txt) and write new sample data in it (do not copy paste from existing file). And then run your code on that file.

Comment: If there is a typo don't make an answer out of it.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation, that is why I had to add it as an answer.